# I can't get Horseman's Blade

Tags: terraria-console

Even though I've gotten to Wave 15 MANY times, I can't get The Horseman's Blade. Can anybody tell me what the percentage rate of the drop is for The Horseman's Blade? I'd really like to know. The Official Wiki doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pumpking), the sword has a drop rate of about **1.79-14.29%** from the Pumpking during the Pumpkin Moon event.  The percentage goes up based on the wave, as denoted by the Wiki:

> Like Mourning Wood, the later the wave Pumpking is killed in, the more likely it is to drop items. Pumpkings defeated during Wave 15 are guaranteed to produce one Pumpking Trophy along with one of its other items.

Comment: What is the increase in percent per round? Is it just from 1.79 to 14.29? Sorry, just confused on the math there.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf see my edit.  The Wiki doesn't say how much exactly.  Wave 15 is the max wave though, and one can say that it goes up by ~.83% each wave, starting at 1.79 on wave 1.  If I'm right, the calculation would be (14.29-1.79) / 15 = ~.83

Comment: Of course that percentage increase per wave may not be exactly correct if the growth isn't linear since it could be a curve but you are best off waiting for 15 to get the kill anyway. @TimmyJim

Comment: thank you for that answer! I am now trying to get horseman's blade again. :)